# jQuery replaceWith() doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the following code some image is fetched from PHP file and the image should be replaced by another image every two seconds.

The problem is only the first image prints to the screen.

I tried the `append()` function but the result is not what I expect.

```
 setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({            
    url: "PHPPage.php", 
    type: "POST",          
    dataType: "HTML", 
    success: function(data) { 
    jQuery('body').replaceWith(data);
    },
    }); 
    });},2000);
```

Comment: What is your current results?

Comment: Does the returned HTML include the `<body>` tag? If not, use `.html` instead of `.replaceWith`.

Comment: @rahilWazir the current results is only first image is show up in html file and i expect to see after 2 seconds another image. if i using the append() all images are streaming to the html file.

Comment: @mooseman HTML file include <body></body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

[replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) replaces "body" element with argument. If "data" does not contain "body" element next interation of the loop will not be able to find any elements with `jQuery('body')`.

So most likely your service does not return `<body>....</body>` as your code expects. Fix:

- either return `<body>...` from server
- replace content instead of element using [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [jQuery.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) depending on whether service returns plain text or HTML.

Comment: actually i'm try to return image from server. i got the same result after change jquery.replaceWith to jquery.html

Comment: If i using the append() function: all images are streaming to the html file.

Comment: @user3552922 - sorry, I have no idea now what you are trying to do. I thought you trying to add text/HTML in body, but it looks like you doing something different. Small sample of service response could be useful.